# When to use a tuple vs list vs dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I was having a discussion with a friend on Facebook today and he's just starting to learn python, as we were discussing he said this,

"I've written a million lines of code over the years and the whole idea of when to use a tuple vs list vs dictionary in python is just vague"

and I am having the exact same issue. Then I suggested he post here with questions and it dawned on me. . . Why don't I POST the question? Since it's a big block for me as well.

So programming nerds. In plain english, how would you best answer this? P.S. I love this website.

Answer (score 9):

Use a tuple to store a sequence of items that will not change.

Use a list to store a sequence of items that may change.

Use a dict when you want to associate pairs of two items.

Comment: although there are exceptions to the rules ocassionally(+1 all the same)

Comment: There is more to it than that. See the link from Xavier in the comments to the question. Most notably, you shouldn't just think of tuples as immutable lists.

Comment: I agree there is a lot more to it.  But this is the simple, straightforward answer.